# SQ L - how to select the next latest 10 records from a specified position in a table?

Tags: mysql

I have a table of pdf titles in a MYSQL database and I am trying to load these dynamically onto my website only 10 at a time as the user scrolls down to the bottom of the page.  I am ok with the ajax request but I am stuck on the SQL statement required to capture the next 10 titles from a specified position in the table.

Let us say the last loaded title had an ID of 10.

My SQL attempt:

```
 SELECT titles FROM pdfLibrary ************ ORDER BY DATE ASC LIMIT 10
```

I would like some help finishing this SQL statement.

Comment: So here you need pagination?

Comment: if you had taken 10 seconds to read the SELECT statement syntax you would have seen LIMIT

Comment: `LIMIT 10 OFFSET n` , n is your starting position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `LIMIT` with an `OFFSET`, e.g.

```
SELECT titles
FROM pdfLibrary
ORDER BY DATE ASC
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10
```

Programatically, you would replace `OFFSET 10` with `OFFSET ID`, assuming you wanted to use the `ID` to keep track of where you were in your count.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 parameters with the Limit for example if you want to get result 10 to 20

```
SELECT titles FROM pdfLibrary ORDER BY DATE ASC LIMIT 10,20;
```

this will return you to records of 10 to 20